# Access to module data from diff module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I've node module and I need to parse the data and I want to share this parsed properties in different modules.the first module which call to this is responsible to pass the data and other modules doesn't need to send the data since I already store the parsedData(in cacheObj)  and the can use just get of any property,the problem is when I access from 1 module and provide the data and then try to access from diff module,the cache object is not contain the data which I "store",any idea how to do it right?

```
"use strict";
var Parser = require('myParser'),
    _ = require('lodash');

function myParser(data) {
    if (!(this instanceof myParser)) return new myParser(data);
    if (!_.isEmpty(this.cacheObj)) {
        this.parsedData = this.cacheObj;
    } else {
        this.parsedData = Parser.parse(data);
        this.cacheObj = this.parsedData;
    }
}

myParser.prototype = {
    cacheObj: {},
    getPropOne: function () {
        return this.parsedData.propOne;
    },

    getPropTwo: function () {
        return this.parsedData.propTwo;
    }
};

module.exports = myParser;
```

The data should be the same for my node app so I dont need to pass it every time...just for "init"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use singleton objects, basic sample below

```
var Singleton = (function () {
    var instance;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new Object("I am the instance");
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();
```

---

In your case, use same approach

```
"use strict";
var Parser = require('myParser'),
    _ = require('lodash');

var cacheObj; // <-- singleton, will hold value and will not be reinitialized on myParser function call

function myParser(data) {
    if (!(this instanceof myParser)) return new myParser(data);
    if (!_.isEmpty(cacheObj)) { //remove `this`
        this.parsedData = cacheObj; //remove `this`
    } else {
        this.parsedData = Parser.parse(data);
        cacheObj = this.parsedData; //remove `this`
    }
}

myParser.prototype = {
    //remove `this.cacheObj`
    getPropOne: function () {
        return this.parsedData.propOne;
    },

    getPropTwo: function () {
        return this.parsedData.propTwo;
    }
};

module.exports = myParser;
```

Using [memory-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache), don't forget to install

```
"use strict";
var Parser = require('myParser'),
    _ = require('lodash');
var cache = require('memory-cache');

function myParser(data) {
    if (!(this instanceof myParser)) return new myParser(data);
    var cache_data = cache.get('foo');
    if (!_.isEmpty(cache_data)) {
        this.parsedData = JSON.parse(cache_data);
    } else {
        this.parsedData = Parser.parse(data);
        cache.put('foo', JSON.stringify(this.parsedData));
    }
}

myParser.prototype = {
    getPropOne: function () {
        return this.parsedData.propOne;
    },

    getPropTwo: function () {
        return this.parsedData.propTwo;
    }
};

module.exports = myParser;
```

Comment: Correct but I want to avoid using global varible (your second eg),there is a way to do it?this is not good design to use it...

Comment: It's not global variable, it exists only in that file

Comment: yes but this is global AFAIK, do you think there it better approach to do that ?

Comment: It  is not global,  for example `var Parser = require('myParser')`, this Parser object can be used inside that file, it's not global, you cannot use it even if you require your script file, it's just javascript hoisting

Comment: Thanks so you are saying that this is a good practice to use it like this?